# Running sonarLint analysis for a directory?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I am using [Sonar-lint](http://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/) for IntelliJ Idea as a static code analysis tool.

From the Sonar-Lint tool window appearing bottom of Intellij, I can run the analysis for **current file** or currently **opened files**.

Is there a way to run that for whole project? or at least for a given directory/package?

[image]